# Hashtable A equals HashtAble B control

Tags: c#, controls, hashtable, equals

Hallo in c# 
i got  two hashtable object of which key/value pair is same
and i want  to check if that two hashtable key/value pairs are equal..

i tried up hashtable's equal method but not worked

should i check all items with foreach?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is take a set union and see if the size is the same as the count.  You could do a set difference but then you'd have to do it both ways.  These can easily be done with Linq extension methods, but since you're using Hashtable you have to use Cast() to get it to IEnumerable:

```
        var table1 = new Hashtable {{"A", 1}, {"B", 2}, {"C", 3}};
        var table2 = new Hashtable {{"B", 2}, {"A", 1}, {"C", 3}};

        bool same = table1.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().Union(table2.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()).Count() == table1.Count;

        Console.WriteLine("Same = " + same);
```

I typically recommend Dictionary over Hashtable to get the type safety, but the Cast<>() lets you use the Linq stuff just find with the old Hashtable.

Answer (score 3):

> i tried up hashtable's equal method but not worked

This will do a reference comparison to see if the two references to hashtables are the same. That is not what you want.

> shoul i check all items with foreach?

Yes. Check that the two hashtables have the same number of items, and that all the key/value pairs in the first are in the second.

Comment: Is it necessary to check both directions? Isn't it enough to verify both hashtables have the same # of keys and that everything in the first is in the second, and key/value pairs are equal?